# Cannot start Weblogic Server from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle, weblogic, freeze

I'm using Eclipse Kepler with Oracle Weblogic Tool plugin and I faced with this problem:

Trying to starting WLS server (both in Run/Debug mode) the process hangs at 23%.
It seams that Eclipse does not run startWeblogic.cmd file. I put into this cmd an instruction (as first instruction) that creates a tmp file on the fly, in order to understand if Eclipse is able or not to run the .cmd file.

Well, the file is not created. No possibility to:

- Stop the process
- Remove the Server from the list

OS: Win 7 64bit

Eclipse: any version (I tried also with Kepler)

WLS: 10.3.4

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried a different/new domain?

Comment: I found the Solution.

Comment: Windows Defender blocks the CMD. After that I killed the process (I noted that it eat up 3.5 GB of memory) automagically Starting WLS process reached 100% in few second.

Comment: sorry the program is Qualcomm Atheros AWiC Diagnosiccs utility, not Windows Defender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution by my self.

Qualcomm Atheros AWiC Diagnosiccs utility blocks the CMD. After that I killed the process (AWiCDiag,exe - I noted that it eat up 3.5 GB of memory) automagically Starting WLS process reached 100% in few second.